# In AWS lamda how to convert my Parquet file to CSV using pandas to_csv and i want that csv file should be inserted to postgresql using PYTHON

Tags: pandas, postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda

Now i am able to fetch the parquet file from AWS s3 and i did some modification to that parquet file in lambda. I am facing problem in inserting this **data** to postgreql database from same lambda. I found a solution of converting this **data** to csv file and inserting in my local system but i am not able to implement code in lambda.
My lambda code is shown below where **data** is the set of **data** recieved from S3

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    **data** = read_data_from_s3(event)
    print('lambda')
    print(data)
    **data**.to_csv('fielname.csv', index = False)
```

This is the error i am facing while converting the data to CSV. If possible suggest me any options to insert this **data** to postgresql database

> [ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'fielname.csv'
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 67, in lambda_handler
> data.to_csv('fielname.csv', index = False)   File "/opt/python/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3551, in to_csv
> return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(   File "/opt/python/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1180, in to_csv
> csv_formatter.save()   File "/opt/python/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 241, in save
> with get_handle(   File "/opt/python/pandas/io/common.py", line 789, in get_handle
> handle = open(

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to your current working directory in lambda. You can **only write to** `/tmp` (by default 500 MB max). So it should be:

```
data.to_csv('/tmp/fielname.csv', index = False)
```